# Reading old clipboard data in new program version in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, clipboard

We have an old program version where we put a serializable class into the clipboard. For this example lets say something like this:

```
namespace ClipboardLibrary
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ClipboardData
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now in the new version to keep it for this example simple the class looks the same except the namespace was changed like so:

```
namespace ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ClipboardData
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I copy now from the old version - where it is done by simply call `SetData(someKey, clipboardData)` and try to get the deserialize the data via `Clipboard.GetData(someKey)` I get a serialization exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233076
  Message=Der für die Deserialisierung benötigte Typ "ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData" kann nicht geladen werden.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
      bei System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
      bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
      bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.ReadObjectFromHandle(IntPtr handle)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataFromHGLOBAL(String format, IntPtr hglobal)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataFromOleHGLOBAL(String format, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataFromBoundOleDataObject(String format, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert)
      bei System.Windows.DataObject.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert)
      bei System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataInternal(String format)
      bei System.Windows.Clipboard.GetData(String format)
      bei CopyPaste.MainWindow.Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\twilker\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CopyPaste\CopyPaste\MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 42.
      ...
```

I am sorry of the German text here. What it says is that the type `ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData` could not be found, which makes obvious sense.

Is there a possibility to retrieve the data anyway somehow?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to deserialize the object?

Comment: See above the exception. I only need to call `Clipboard.GetData(someKey)`

Comment: Have a look at custom [Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and potentially also [Binary Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Problem with this is, that the customer has already the product and no changes on the old version can be made.

Comment: How does the other program sets the data to clipboard? That will be little helpful.

Comment: See the description above the exception for details.

Comment: What is that `someKey`? I'm not sure it matters. Because I can't reproduce the problem. I get the object as `MemoryStream` instead

Comment: In my case it is "Test". `clipboardData` is an instance of the old `ClipboardData` class. I do not put a `MemoryStream` into the clipboard

Answer (score 3):

You can reference old assembly in the new one and obtain `ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData` `Type` via deserialization without exceptions. And implement in the new assembly convertor from `ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData` to `ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace.ClipboardData`.

Comment: Would it not result in conflicts when there are other types beside the ClipboardData where the namespaces were not moved and therefore are still in the same namespace?

Comment: Since you moved the class `ClipboardData` from the old NS to the new NS already, you will need to use your current `ClipboardData` class with `OtherNamespace.ClipboardData` instead of just `ClipboardData` until all old version of your application are out of production and you can remove the old definition

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to make it work when interacting with `Clipboard`. Because deserialization isn't with our control(AFAIK).

If you're directly dealing with `BinaryFormatter` you can create a custom [SerializationBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as below.

```
public class CustomSerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName == "ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData")
        {
            return typeof(ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace.ClipboardData);
        }
        return Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                typeName, assemblyName));
    }
}

private ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace.ClipboardData DeSerialize(Stream stream)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Binder = new CustomSerializationBinder();
    return (ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace.ClipboardData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

With that, we're asking the `BinaryFormatter` to load `ClipboardLibrary.OtherNamespace.ClipboardData` type when it asks for `ClipboardLibrary.ClipboardData`. Sort of type redirection.

Comment: @adricadar Oh, how will you do otherwise given that we don't have the type now?

Comment: Your code is awesome and solve the problem, you can pass the namespace in constructor or somewhere else, this way will be more generic.

Comment: How does it some the problem? How can I use this of the clipboard?

Comment: @Yggdrasil Can you post the stacktrace of the exception. Let me see if I can get more info with that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution would be to define a class in the old namespace along the one in the new namespace and then after it deserializes successfully map the old one to the new one.

Comment: I will try it and report back.

Comment: you can inherit one (the new one?) class from the other to avoid duplicate code

Comment: Lets assume they have not changed and we simply fixed the namespace for our classes. In this case I would always have to take the garbage from the old version with me.