# How to replace a legacy class with a new ISerializable class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, c++-cli, binaryformatter

We have a legacy class `A` which is `[Serializable]`, but not `ISerializable`.
For miscellaneous reasons, this class has to be patched to implement ISerializable.

The problem is that we still need to be able to load old save files, which used .NET's default implementation for serialization of class `A`.
In other words, when loading old savefiles, class `A` must be deserialized like the old version and then be converted to the new version of class `A`, such that when saving again, our new implementation of `ISerializable` is used.

What is the most decent way to patch class `A` without breaking backward compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

Firstly, change the assembly version of your project.

```
// AssemblyInfo.cs:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

Create a new type for the savegame data.

```
// The legacy savegame data. Keep it as it is.
[Serializable]
public class Savegame
{
    // ... the legacy fields
}

// The new savegame data. This implements ISerializable
[Serializable]
public class SavegameNew : Savegame, ISerializable
{
    // this constructor will execute on deserialization. You will deserialize
    // both the legacy and new types here.
    private SavegameNew(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            // you can iterate the serialized elements like this
            // if this is a new format you will get the new elements, too
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // custom serialization of the new type
    }
}
```

Now you need a binder class that maps the legacy format to the new one:

```
internal class SavegameBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // Of course, use the assembly version of the old version here.
        // You don't even need to change the assembly version, though than can lead to ambiguity
        AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
        if (asmName.Version == new Version(1, 0, 0, 0) && typeName == typeof(Savegame).FullName)
            return typeof(SavegameNew);

        // otherwise we do not change the mapping
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
// the saveStream can contain either the old other the new format
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter() { Binder = new SavegameBinder() };
SavegameNew data = (SavegameNew)bf.Deserialize(saveStream);
```

### Solution 2

With this solution you don't need to map `Savegame` to `SavegameNew`. If you don't change the assembly version, you don't even need the binder class.

If you changed the assembly version, the `SavegameBinder` should return the `Savegame` type of the new assembly. The legacy `Savegame` should implement the `IObjectReference` interface, so once it has been deserialized, it can return a `SavegameNew` instance.

```
// The legacy savegame data
[Serializable]
public class Savegame: IObjectReference
{
    // ... the legacy fields

    public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
    {
        return new SavegameNew(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reminds me my [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29922877/2530848) :) This should work. +1

Comment: Didn't know about IObjectReference, thanks for that! About the first solution, how do I parse the serialization entries in case of a legacy type?

Comment: If the legacy type has been serialized as a default object graph, the `SerializationInfo` will contain the field names. If it has a base type, the fields from the base will be prefixed with the type name. That's why I've suggested the `foreach` in the constructor, you can simply dump the entry names to see keys of the serialized data.